# How do I determine the correct Visual Studio version for source?

Tags: visual-studio

I am retrieving old programs from source control & visual studio tells me that the source needs to be converted.
How can I tell which version of Visual Studio is required to open a source without conversion?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to do this is to open the solution file in your text editor of choice which will give you the version of visual studio in the header like

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 14
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.24720.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 14.0.24720.0
```

Then look that up somewhere like this table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History)

To find out the correct version

Comment: What do you call the header file, the .sln file?

Comment: Yes @SteveStaple the .sln file